# Why does an `ajax:success' event not fire in Rails system test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a system test that fails because the proper `ajax:success` event is not being fired in the test environment. The event is correctly fired when testing manually in the browser.

Here's the link the user (and the test) clicks:

```
link_to 'Note', note_product_option_path(@product, option), remote: true, data: { note_link: true }
```

The JS (CoffeeScript) event, which takes the response and inserts into the `body` of the document:

```
NOTE_LINK = '[data-note-link="true"]'
$ ->
  $('body').on 'ajax:success', NOTE_LINK, (e) ->
    alert 'ajax:success'
    $('.option-note').remove()
    data = e.detail[2].response        
    $div = $('<div></div>').html(data)
      .addClass('option-note')
    $('body').append($div)
```

Here's the system testing setup:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1480x1680')
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :options => options)
  end
end
```

In my system test:

```
visit product_path(option.product)
click_link 'Note'
assert_selector '.option-note', wait: 5
```

That assertion always fails, even though it always works when I test in the browser. The `alert` is never caught or fired by Capybara either, but always appears when manually checking. The test log shows that the proper JS is being rendered by the controller.

What am I missing here?

Comment: the page probably isn't ready yet when the JS gets executed. You'll either need to use the onReady function OR use a bind function to ensure the execution can happen. To me this is proven by the chrome console working on a fully rendered page.

Comment: @engineerDave - you're right, the document ready isn't firing in testing for some reason. Not sure why or how to fix. Tried running Selenium Chrome (non-headless) but same result.

Comment: yeah this is the main reason ppl skimp on feature tests, JS. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the browser console for any other JS errors and fix them.  The big difference between the development and test environments is that the JS assets get concatenated into one file in the test environment which means an error in one JS can prevent JS from other files being run. In the development mode that doesn’t happen because each file is loaded separately so an error can only affect other code in the same file

Comment: There are no errors, either in the console, or from `page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)` in the test.

Comment: @croceldon have you tried sleeping for a few seconds between the visit and click_link?  That would rule out the click happening before the page is ready. The other thing to check is that your asset pipeline is working - try  `rake assets:clobber` to wipe out the current asset compilation and force a rebuild